# Can other "building blocks" be used to define a CW complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

When we define a CW complex, we use closed balls as its "building blocks." But is there a concept using more general building blocks, maybe something like a topological space equipped with one of its closed set (so that a topological space would behave like a closed ball $D^n$ and the closed set would behave like $S^{n-1}$)?

Comment: Of course you can glue together whatever you want, I think May has maybe even axiomatized what you might want your building blocks to contain. The reason we use CW complexes primarily is that for them homotopy equivalences and maps that induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups are the same thing.

Comment: @Connor I see. Do you have a link containing May's axiomatization?

Comment: Actually, he does the dual generalization which is about Postnikov towers. I am not sure how helpful it is, but it is in chapter 3 of "More concise".